# Loading view data from memory instead of disk

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I noticed Laravel reads the view files from the disk before every render. Is there any way I can cache the view content to memory and render the view without reading it from file?

**I do not want to cache the rendered view but to load the view file (.blade) from memory before rendering it.**

Edit:

Based on the answered I received on other forums, there are limited benefits in loading the view files from memory as the file system already does have a caching mechanism.

Response from Laracast Forum

> When you call a view from your application Laravel will compile the
>   blade template into PHP and cache the contents in
>   storage/framework/views so that subsequent requests for the same
>   content do not need to recompile the template.
>
> I am not aware of a way within the framework to configure the view
>   cache to use an alternate in memory cache like Redis.
>
> I would be surprised if the disk I/O caused by reading views from disk
>   would cause a huge amount of Disk I/O but there are tools like iostat
>   and pidstat that you can use to determine if this is a bottleneck for
>   you.
>
> One possible solution would be to mount the view cache folder as a
>   separate tmpfs mountpoint
>
> mount -t tmpfs -o size=128M tmpfs /your/path/storage/framework/views
>   This will temporarily mount the folder in memory (with a max size of
>   128Mb which you can tweak). if you want to make this permanent you
>   need to add to /etc/fstab as per link above.
>
> Feel free to try but to be honest IMO you are going to get limited
>   benefits.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some sort of memory caching, you could manually render the view and cache the result.
However, I do not think this will give you any big speed improvements.

```
$view = cache()->remember('view_home.index', 30, function() {
    return view('home.index');
});

return response($view);
```

Remember that php has to read all classes from disk as well so, caching a few files from a hundred won't speed up your website.

Comment: I don't want to cache the rendered results, I want to load the view content from memory before rendering it. The app runs on CLI so everything is already loaded except the view files which are loaded from disk for every render.